# ExifInterface: getAttribute for TAG_USER_COMMENT only returns "UNICODE"

Tags: java, android, android-exifinterface

I am using ExifInterface to read the UserComments EXIF tag in a jpeg file in my Java Android Studio app.

I can use the exiftool command in Linux to verify that there IS data in the UserComment field.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(inputStream);
String s = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT);
```

When this is run, the string s contains "UNICODE".

Any idea what's up with that?

Also, I plan on reading other EXIF tags. Can I make multiple calls to getAttribute() or do I need to reset the stream between calls somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exif is not a stream.

Comment: ExifInterface() can have an InputStream, File, filename or file descriptor as it's parameter. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface

Comment: Does not matter. Irrelevant. That the exif header is read from a stream does not make it a stream. You can call members of your exif instance as oft as you want as the exif instance is no stream.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your first comment. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Figured the first part out.

Instead of using exif.getAttribute(), I used exif.getAttributeBytes(). This reads it into a byte array. I then use the String function to convert the byte array into a string. After doing that, there is still the characters "UNICODE" stuck on the front of the string, so I trim that off with substr().

Here is the result:

```
byte[] s = exif.getAttributeBytes(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT);
String u = new String(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).substring(7);
```